# Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin

Tags: javascript, postcss, postcss-url

This is my postcss configuration code in rollup.config.js file:

```
const postcssUrlOpts = [
    {
        url: 'copy',
        filter: /\.woff$/,
        assetsPath: 'font'
    }
];

const postcssOpts = {
    extract: 'index.css',
    plugins: [
        postcssUrl(postcssUrlOpts)
    ]
};
```

And this is the log that I get:

```
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
    at Processor.normalize (/.../node_modules/rollup-plugin-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.es6:130:15)
    at new Processor (/.../node_modules/rollup-plugin-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.es6:38:25)
    at postcss (/.../node_modules/rollup-plugin-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.es6:34:10)
    at /.../node_modules/rollup-plugin-postcss/dist/index.js:213:28
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/.../node_modules/rollup-plugin-postcss/dist/index.js:19:24)
    at _next (/.../node_modules/rollup-plugin-postcss/dist/index.js:41:9)
```

Without postcssUrl plugin all my css imports in javascript files are working and everything is fine but when I add this plugin to
the list of postcss plugins I get this error in my console. Any other plugin like tailwindcss plugin works just fine.

versions:

```
postcss: ^8.1.10
postcss-url: ^10.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the `plugins` array should be functions. You're calling the function immediately and returning the object. Wrap the function call in a function.

```
const postcssOpts = {
    extract: 'index.css',
    plugins: [
        () => postcssUrl(postcssUrlOpts)
    ]
};
```

Comment: Hi. Now there is no error but It's not copying my fonts to "font" folder. I saw multiple example of postcss-url configuration examples and all of those were immediate function call. I add an issue in postcss-url github page but unfortunately there is no one answering my issue there. Also I should also mention that before upgrading dependencies, It was just working fine.

Comment: Also adding tailwindcss 2.0 plugin as immediate function call just works fine.